# Implementing TrustedShop from compari.ro in Magento 1

Tags: php, magento

can anyone help me with this problem? I need some advice to install this plugin: TrustedShop in Magento. I have a documentation from them but they didn't say exactly where to put the files. There is the documentation: [Documentation](http://www.compari.ro/admin/trustedshop/doc/TrustedShopDocumentation-RO.pdf). I have the TrustedShop.php file. The problem is not the code, the problem is where to put it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Place it where it is accessible and include it with

```
    require_once('/PATH/TrustedShop.php');
```

at the top of the php-script(s).